# creating a new table using result set from union all

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to create a new table using the result set of two tables
the query is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE final_sales_churn_Data AS (
select * from test_data
union all 
select * from train_data
);
```

i get an error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'union all select * from train_data)' at line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the parentheses.  Just drop them:

```
create table final_sales_churn_Data as
    select * from test_data
    union all
    select * from train_data;
```